# MATLAB: Keeping a number of random rows in a matrix which satisfy certain conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I have a matrix in Matlab which looks similar to this, except with thousands of rows:

```
A =

     5     6     7     8
     6     1     2     3
     5     1     4     8
     5     2     3     7
     5     8     7     2
     6     1     3     8
     5     2     1     6
     6     3     2     1
```

I would like to get out a matrix that has three random rows with a '5' in the first column and three random rows with a '6' in the first column. So in this case, the output matrix would look something like this:

```
A =

     5     6     7     8
     6     1     2     3
     5     2     3     7
     6     1     3     8
     5     2     1     6
     6     3     2     1
```

The rows must be random, not just the first three or the last three in the original matrix. 
I'm not really sure how to begin this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: This is the most successful attempt I've had so far. I found all the rows with a '5' in the first column:

```
BLocation = find(A(:,1) == 5);
B = A(BLocation,:);
```

Then I was trying to use 'randsample' like this to find three random rows from B:

```
C = randsample(B,3);
```

But 'randsample' does not work with a matrix.

I also think this could be done a little more efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run `randsample` on the row indices that satisfy the conditions, i.e. equality to 5 or 6.

```
n = size(A,1);

% construct the linear indices for rows with 5 and 6 
indexA = 1:n; 
index5 = indexA(A(:,1)==5);
index6 = indexA(A(:,1)==6);

% sample three (randomly) from each 
nSamples = 3;
r5 = randsample(index5, nSamples);
r6 = randsample(index6, nSamples);

% new matrix from concatenation 
B = [A(r5,:); A(r6,:)];
```

**Update**: You can also use `find` to replace the original index construction, as yuk suggested, which proves to be faster (and optimized!).

**Bechmark** (MATLAB R2012a)

```
A = randi(10, 1e8, 2); % 10^8 rows random matrix of 1-10

tic;
n = size(A,1);
indexA = 1:n;
index5_1 = indexA(A(:,1)==5);
toc

tic;
index5_2 = find(A(:,1)==5);
toc

Elapsed time is 1.234857 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.679076 seconds.
```

Comment: @yuk if you get the same output, why would you have the overhead of calling find, since you can directly index 1:n, i.e. the vector of row indices? By the above you use logical indexing only on the vector 1:n, which you construct analytically. Unless `find` is doing some additional performance optimization, I'm assuming it will be slower for larger matrices. It doesn't require the allocation of a new vector in memory though.

Comment: @gevang I checked your code for speed. It does not slow down much for larger matrices. My code (the answer below) is faster for small matrices (about 10000 rows) but after that its execution time starts increasing. I think that is because I am concatenating.

Comment: @gevang, I tested timing of your code vs. find on a matrix with million rows (indices construction only) and find is about twice faster. It faster even if `indexA` creation is not counted. Probably due to find optimization.

Comment: @yuk awesome! you are right. I didn't know that and wouldn't have checked. I thought by default find has an overhead. Updating with a small benchmark.

Comment: @Parag as @yuk also points out `randsample()` calls `randperm()`. You can always factor-out the relevant call to `randperm`. Anyway, I gave an alternative answer to yours, using `randsample` which the OP mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows:

```
desiredMat=[];
mat1=A(A(:,1)==5,:);
mat1=mat1(randperm(size(mat1,1)),:);
desiredMat=[desiredMat;mat1(1:3,:)];
mat1=A(A(:,1)==6,:);
mat1=mat1(randperm(size(mat1,1)),:);
desiredMat=[desiredMat;mat1(1:3,:)];
```

The above code uses logical indexing. You can also do this with `find` function (logical indexing is always faster than `find`).

Comment: Yes, this code is more then twice faster than from @gevand. First `randperm` is build-in function. `randsample` actually calls `randperm`. Second probably due to direct indexing. I'd only advice not to grow `desireMat`. Better to create `mat2` and concatenate them with `desiredMat=[mat1(1:3,:); mat2(1:3,:)];`. A little faster.